# Recorded audio fails to play on device but not iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVAudioRecorder to record audio in one view controller and then display recorded audio on a table in another

```
var numberOfRecords = 0

var recordingSession:AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!

@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: UIButton) {
// Check if we have an active audio recorder
if audioRecorder == nil {

    numberOfRecords = numberOfRecords + 1
    let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")
    let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 12000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

    // Start audio recording
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
        print(filename)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()
    } catch {
        displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "Recording Failed")
    }
} else {
    // Stopping audio recording
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil
    UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
}

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Record
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        if let number:Int = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myNumber") as? Int {
            numberOfRecords = number
        }
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { (hasPermission) in
            if hasPermission {
            }
        }

    }
```

That's the code to record audio in the first view controller and here's the code to playback the audio in the second view controller

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

When I try to play it back on my iPhone I get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "(null)"
```

I've been having this issue for many weeks and still haven't found a solution. I've tried a lot of things online like changing the AVSampleRateKey, the file type it saves as and nothing works. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I don't know if it's the fact that I'm recording in one view controller and playing in another but it only plays back the audio in the Xcode simulator and not my physical device.

more code to viewdidload:

```
do {
    try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try recordingSession.setActive(true)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { (hasPermission) in
        if hasPermission {
        }
    }
} catch {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are mishandling your audio session. It is *crucial*. You must *not* retain a reference to your audio session like that; it is not a thing, but a pipeline to talk to the media services daemon. For recording, you must configure a Recording *category* on the session, and you must *activate* the session. For playback, change your category to a playback category and activate *that* session.

Comment: YES!!!This did the job! Thank so you much you have no idea how much that helped me!lol

Comment: So I managed to get the recording to work by including more code in my viewDidLoad. I added the code in my original question at the bottom. It records now but other sounds in the app are very quiet.

Comment: Remember the second half of what I said. When done recording, deactivate your audio session, change its category to a playback category, and activate again. Now play back.